# Web Browsers for Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, browser

I'm working on Oracle Linux as a development machine. I'm looking for a web browser, but I can't seem to find them:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i web
pywebkitgtk-1.1.6-3.el6.x86_64
webkitgtk-1.2.6-5.el6.x86_64
kurdit-unikurd-web-fonts-20020502-6.el6.noarch
$ rpm -qa | grep -i browser
```

I tried to install Chrome, Chromium, Opera and Dillo, but:

```
$ sudo yum install chrome
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
No package chrome available.
Error: Nothing to do
$ sudo yum install chromium
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
No package chromium available.
Error: Nothing to do
$ sudo yum install opera
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
No package opera available.
Error: Nothing to do
$ sudo yum install dillo
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
No package dillo available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Does anyone know what browsers are available (besides `lynx`, which is painful for me to use)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installed Oracle Linux web browser is called [Konqueror](https://apps.kde.org/konqueror/), you may find it in “Applications -> Internet menu.”

Otherwise, when you have properly set up yum, you can issue:

```
sudo yum install firefox
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. Isn't Konqueror KDE (I'm running Gnome)? Also, I don't use Firefox (too many bad choices and two virus/malware infections though FF).

Comment: What do you have under Applications -> Internet?

Comment: And, btw, no, I think konqueror exists in Gnome too.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I don't have anything under "Applications -> Internet" because its missing (the menuh has system and admin stuff, and almost no user stuff). Let me install ala carte and see if I can display it. Thanks again.

Comment: @noloader you might perhaps take a look here, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2213435?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

#### Chromium:

You can also install Chromium (feels like Google Chrome) on Oracle Linux Release 7 like this:

```
sudo yum install chromium --enablerepo=ol7_developer_EPEL
```

#### Google Chrome:

Google chrome can also be installed by creating the following repo file `/etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo` with contents:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Now install Google Chrome like this:

```
sudo yum install google-chrome
```